# iframe center in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I'm having difficulty getting this iframe (youtube video) to center.
I'm using bootstrap and here's my code:

```
<div class="su-youtube su-responsive-media-yes"><iframe
    width="400"
    height="320"
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/SGOc9P4Ynm?modestbranding=1&controls=0&iv_load_policy=3&rel=0&showinfo=0&color=white"
    frameborder="0"></iframe> </div>
```

I've tried adding the class "center-block" and "text-center" too and also tried removing the iframe from the div. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS:

```
.su-youtube {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

### [CODEPEN EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOKEJm)

Comment: Yes but I added styles to that class and it centers your YouTube video.

Comment: does not work for giphy here: https://giphy.com/gifs/season-8-the-simpsons-8x21-l0G170YiUYqwSSgeI/embed

Answer (score 0):

This has just worked for me. Bootstrap4

```
    <div class="container text-center"> 

<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="<Your youtube video>" allowfullscreen width="50%" height="300px" style="border-radius:20px;background:#ffffff;padding:5px;"></iframe> 

</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).